# running command line programs in background using python os or subprocess module

Tags: python, python-2.7, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am trying to run a command using `os` or `subproccess` module in python. the command prompt window briefly flickers before terminating. Is there a way of eliminating that popping up of command prompt window..?

For example:

```
os.system("ffmpeg -i output.wav output.flac")
```

Is there a way I can run this in the background so that user may not notice this..?

I am running windows 7 with python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would be to try to take advantage of the [`subproccess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) modules partial support for the [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. Something like this:

```
info = subprocess.STARTUP_INFO()
info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

process = subprocess.Popen("ffmpeg -i output.wav output.flac", startupinfo=info)
process.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

of coarse   ... you even tagged it with the module you would use ...

```
subproccess.Popen("ffmpeg -i output.wav output.flac".split(),shell=True).communicate()
```

should do it ...

Comment: I think you mean `shell=False`.

Comment: shell=True will tell it to use the system environment ... so that you dont have to pass in things like env ... `shell=False` will likely break unless ffmpeg is in the same folder as the script or an absolute path is passed in

Comment: You can't pass a list of arguments if you're using `shell=True`, it has to be a string. And when you use `shell=False` you still get the system environment, you're just not actually spawning a shell to execute the command. Also, OP is specifically looking to avoid a command prompt window briefly appearing when the command runs, which I imagine using `shell=True` would not prevent (don't have a Windows machine to verify this, though).

Comment: yeah it looks like you're right it doesn't need to pass shell is true on Windows... my bad

Answer (score 0):

`def asyncRun(command):
    os.system(command)`

`t = Thread(target=asyncRun, args=('ping 127.0.0.1 -s 271',))
t.start()`

works on windows 10 + EMET + 2.7